# Android, internet connection and no answer for ordinary calling

Tags: android, voice

I wrote simple application, for my Galaxy SII, for permanent connection with remote server. Ones for 5 second it sends and receives data. While application is working nobody can't call to me. Network answers him - interlocutor is unavailable.
The same happend me when I use mail client like K-9. It doesn't matter I use GPRS or 3G connection.

What is a main rule (if is it?) to construct internet application to avoid this problem (I mean problem with ordinary incomming phone connection)?

My ordinary code for sending data (in remote service) is like this:

```
While (condition)
{
try {
Thread.sleep(500);
} catch (InterruptedException e1) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e1.printStackTrace();
}

try {
    out.write(data + "\n");
    out.flush();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

Regards,
Artik

Comment: There is no relation between `internet connection` and `incoming phone` calls! what are you trying to do exactly? post your code

Comment: Yes, I think like you wrote but my practice (and my friends practice with SGSII) shows strange problem like I wrote. There many time when nobody can call to us when internet connection is using. My simple application is only example. It happens even I use ordinary web browser on the phone.

Comment: Consider how this is affecting the user experience by doing this. The constant connection is draining the battery and potentially reducing the performance. Think more about your use case and why you think you need to connect so regularly. Surely using a push mechanism from your server would be more efficient. Things like the ARO tool https://developer.att.com/aro and the guides here will help you understand more https://developer.att.com/developer/forward.jsp?passedItemId=7200042

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, if you want to wait for **5 seconds** you should use  `Thread.sleep(5000);` **not** `Thread.sleep(500);` which is half a second.

Second, consider sending your data to the server using `Timer` instead of `Thread.sleep()` and `while(condition)`

After modifying your code with the above suggestions, try to test from the `emulator` and simulate a *phone call*.

Comment: Thank you. I will do according to your answer.